# Justify content across multiple cards using material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

This Should be easy but I still cannot figure it out, frontend is not my forte. I have multiple cards MUI cards which are responsive and fixed height. The content of each card consits of a title, description, divider and author. The problem that while the cards remain fixed height the content is not justified correctly. In the example below the divider and author of the card on the right should match the position of the card on the left. Hopefully its an easy fix that I am missing.

[image]

There are ajax calls that renders the data so not a complete example but perhaps this helps

Function that renders the cards

```
    const renderCard = manuscripts?.map((obj, idx) => {
        return(
            <Grid item key={idx} xs={12} sm={4} md={3}>
                <ManuscriptCard 
                    manuscript={obj}
                    onClick={() => alert("Navigate")}
                />
            </Grid>
        );
    });
```

The card component

```
        <BaseStyleCard
            elevation={8}
        >
            <CardActionArea
                onClick={props.onClick}
                sx={{
                    flexGrow: 1,
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    alignItems: "stretch",
                }}
            >
                <CardMedia
                    component="img"
                    alt=""
                    height="140"
                    image="https://picsum.photos/200/500/"
                />
                <CardContent
                >
                    <Grid 
                        sx={{ flexGrow:1 }}
                        container 
                        spacing={2} 
                        direction="column"
                    >
                        <Grid item>
                            <Typography variant="h5">
                                <strong>{props.manuscript.title}</strong>
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
className='editor'></div> */}
                            <Typography variant="body2">
                                {props.manuscript.summary}
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Divider/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Stack
                                justifyContent="space-between"
                                direction="row"
                            >
                                <Typography variant="subtitle2" color="text.secondary">
                                    {firstAuthor?.last_name} et al | { publishedDate }
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography variant="subtitle2" color="text.secondary">
                                    <strong>{props.manuscript.type}</strong>
                                </Typography>
                            </Stack>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </CardContent>
            </CardActionArea>
            <CardActions>
                <Button size="small" color="primary">
                    Share
                </Button>
            </CardActions>
        </BaseStyleCard>
```

The css for the base card

```
export const BaseStyleCard = styled(Card)({
    overflowWrap: "break-word",
    height: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
});
```

Thanks so much to anyone who can offer some help.

I tried changing flexbox parameters and could get the cardActionArea to match the size of the larger card but the content still does not justify properly. I also tried setting justifyContent on the grid container as well as the cardContent component.

Comment: As far as I understood your requirement, You can give "min-height" to title and description and It will work. We can help you more, if you provide sandbox to us, In case you haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a responsive grid of MUI cards, each containing certain content elements. To ensure that the content within each card is aligned properly, you can make a few adjustments to your code. It's great that you're using Flexbox for layout, but there are a couple of things to consider:

**Vertical Alignment of Card Contents:**
To make sure the content within each card is aligned correctly, you can set alignItems: "start" on the CardContent component. This will align the content at the top of the card's content area. This is important because the default value of alignItems is "stretch", which can lead to content elements not aligning correctly.

```
<CardContent sx={{ alignItems: "start" }}>
  {/* ... rest of your content ... */}
</CardContent>
```

**Vertically Centering Divider and Author:**
To vertically center the divider and author at the bottom of the card content, you can use the alignItems property of the Stack component. By setting it to "center", the items within the Stack will be centered vertically.

```
<Stack justifyContent="space-between" direction="row" alignItems="center">
  {/* ... your author and divider elements ... */}
</Stack>
```

With these changes, your card component should ensure that the content within each card is aligned properly and the divider and author are vertically centered within the card's content area.

Here's a modified version of your card component with these changes incorporated:

```
<BaseStyleCard elevation={8}>
  <CardActionArea onClick={props.onClick} sx={{ flexGrow: 1, flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "stretch" }}>
    <CardMedia component="img" alt="" height="140" image="https://picsum.photos/200/500/" />
    <CardContent sx={{ alignItems: "start" }}>
      <Grid sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} container spacing={2} direction="column">
        <Grid item>
          <Typography variant="h5">
            <strong>{props.manuscript.title}</strong>
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Typography variant="body2">{props.manuscript.summary}</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Divider />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Stack justifyContent="space-between" direction="row" alignItems="center">
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" color="text.secondary">
              {firstAuthor?.last_name} et al | {publishedDate}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" color="text.secondary">
              <strong>{props.manuscript.type}</strong>
            </Typography>
          </Stack>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </CardContent>
  </CardActionArea>
  <CardActions>
    <Button size="small" color="primary">
      Share
    </Button>
  </CardActions>
</BaseStyleCard>
```

By making these adjustments, the content within each card should be aligned correctly, and the divider and author should be vertically centered within the card's content area, matching the position of the card on the left.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I tried it but it didn't work correctly. I think the issue is the cardActionArea. Some of your suggestions were very helpfull to get a better layout though, thanks! I eventually gave up and added the author and divider line outside the cardActionArea